# php5-curl not getting installed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, php, ubuntu-14.04, google-compute-engine

I have execute the below

```
sudo apt-get install php5-curl
```

result was

```
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# sudo apt-get install php5-curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php5-curl is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgcrypt11-dev libgnutls-dev libgnutlsxx27 libgpg-error-dev libp11-kit-dev
  librtmp-dev libtasn1-6-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html#
```

But when i try php -m command it shows only below modules.Kindly help me on this

```
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
date
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mhash
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
Zend OPcache
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Did you restart apache afterwards using "service apache2 restart"? Have a look at this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-is-not-installed-in-your-php-installation

Comment: yes I did. `root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                 [Wed Aug 10 10:28:18.833168 2016] [so:warn] [pid 21270] AH01574: module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
                                                                                                                                                                          [ OK ]
root@digin-demo-app:/var/www/html# `

Answer (score 1):

Enable PHP module with this command:

```
sudo php5enmod curl
```

And restart your apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```